# Show only staff name in radio button and user can choose staff name, input price as well

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to show only the staff lists on the radio button to the front end. Then the user can choose the staff name and then input the price and submit. So the system will take staff name (chosen by User) and price as input. So far I was trying to filter the staff name like

```
staff = User.objects.filter(is_staff=True)
```

but I am unable to pass the value to the front end.

So I want to show a list of staff names and then the user chooses the staff name and inputs the price.

As the views.py file is quite big, so I am sharing the gist file [view.py](https://gist.github.com/TaufiqurRahman45/104b571873531d3d119295bb3c24b4fb)

Could anyone please help me out? Thank you

Comment: In your view, at the line 32 of the gist. `if user.balance > 0: user.balance -= price`. This error prone. What `if user.balance - price < 0` ??? Try instead `if user.balance - price >= 0: ...`.

Comment: And in **Django radio button are boolean field** `True` or `False`. If you want to use radio button for more than 2 values, then use choiceFields. Or a custom frontend radio button submitted by `AJAX`.